# Knockout foreach loop binding not working

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

i have wrote below script but the data binding with foreach loop is not happening. Kindly let me know what i am doing wrong here... i tried to use $data, $root etc. but yet i am not able to bind the data to the table.

and kindly let me know if there is any view model debugging tool and how to use it.

**Typescript**

```
    import * as ko from "knockout";

    class Meal {
        mealName: string
        price: number

        constructor(meal: string, price: number) {
            this.mealName = meal;
            this.price = price;
        }
    }

    class SeatReservation {
        passengerName: string
        selectedMeal: Meal

        constructor(name: string, meal: Meal) {
            this.passengerName = name;
            this.selectedMeal = meal;
        }
    }

    class PassengerViewModel {

        availableMeals: Meal[]
        seats: SeatReservation[]

        constructor() {
            var self = this;
            self.availableMeals = [
                new Meal("Sandwich", 10),
                new Meal("Chicken Biriyani", 100),
                new Meal("Al Faham", 1000)
            ];
            self.seats = [
                new SeatReservation("Iliyas", this.availableMeals[0]),
                new SeatReservation("Sri", this.availableMeals[0])
            ];
        }
    }

    let vm = new PassengerViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Passenger Name</th>
            <th>Meal</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><strong data-bind="text: passengerName">todo</strong></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works fine for me when I created a fiddle with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/fc4we2ja/ Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no i didnt get any error in console

Comment: It's very hard to fix an issue if it can't be reproduced.

Comment: @adiga can you please put this code in your local editor and try?

Comment: I don't need to. If the typescript files didn't trasnpile properly, then `new PassengerViewModel()` would throw an error. Since, `PassengerViewModel` is available and the bindings are working properly in the fiddle, there isn't much I can do here. It's possible that none of the javascript code has run on the browser. Place multiple breakpoints in the javascript file and debug.

Comment: Is knockout referenced in your view? can you see the KO file in within developer tools?

Comment: yes KO file is referanced. i am able to see the value if i create a simple string varialbe in ts and bind it in html. but its not binding with table :(

Comment: Are these `seats` coming from database or have you hardcoded as posted in the question? You can try changing it to `self.seats = ko.observableArray( [ new SeatReservation(....), new SeatReservation(......) ] )`